# Autofill last row + 1 to last row + 10

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to autofill last row + 1 to last row + 10, but getting a syntax error...I think because of the quotation marks within the Range property, but not sure how to fix this.

```
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
Range("O" & lrow + 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("O" & lrow + 1:"O" & lrow + 10)
```

Comment: `Destination:=Range("O" & lrow + 1 & ":O" & lrow + 10)`

Comment: `:"` should be `& ":`

Comment: Or replaced by a comma: `Range("O" & (lrow + 1)).AutoFill Destination:=Range("O" & (lrow + 1), "O" & (lrow + 10))`

Comment: after you modify the code to conform with what @BigBen said. shouldn't you start autofilling from the last row because there is nothing in the `lrow+1` row

Comment: You could simplify things by using `Resize`  - `Range("O" & lrow + 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("O" & lrow + 1).Resize(10)`,